# JavaFX label text not showing

Tags: java, javafx

I am following a JavaFX book and one of the examples to show text within the window but there is no text shown within the window. Please help.

```
        package sample;
        import javafx.application.Application;
        import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
        import javafx.scene.Parent;
        import javafx.scene.Scene;
        import javafx.scene.layout.*;
        import javafx.scene.control.*;
        import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
        import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }


    public void start(Stage myStage){

        myStage.setTitle("Demonstrate a Simple Scene Graph");
        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane();
        Scene myScene = new Scene (rootNode,500,500);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);
        Label myLabel = new Label ("A simple JavaFX label.");
        rootNode.getChildren().add(myLabel);
        myStage.show();
    }
}
```

I am using intelij with project SDK 10, and project language 10.

Thank you in advance!

update on 29th July 2018. Managed to resolve the problem. Simply input 
" -Dprism.order=sw " excluding the double quotation mark into VM options.

I found the solution here : https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/84w6i6/problem_displaying_anything_with_javafx_only/

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Try rebuilding before running again.

Comment: The example works fine. I try it also in JDK 10 .
sounds your problem not in code try to clean and build your project.

Comment: I restart writing the code but seemed it is still the same still.